# How to set custom output handlers for argparse in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, argparse

I have configured `logger` to print both onto terminal `stdout` and to a file so I can have an archive of logging messages that I can refer to.

That is easily accomplished by adding a `FileHandler` to your `logging` object. Easy peasy.

What I want to accomplish now is to make `argparse` log also to the same file along with logs to stdout when it encounters parsing errors. So far it only prints to `stdout`. I looked in the `argparse` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) but I can't find anything about setting a different output stream or pipe for `argparse`.

Is it possible to do? How?

Comment: Where did the comment of @wim go? The tip was to override `argparse` module's stderr by overriding value of `argparse._sys.stderr`. This actually works but now it only writes to the file and not to stdout anymore.

Comment: Hi.  I removed that comment because @James Mills posted a much superior solution.

Comment: @radj See my response for a way to redirect both ``stdout`` and ``stderr`` streams to guarantee you catch all output from ``argparser.ArgumentParser``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [argparse.py source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/293d9964cf6e/Lib/argparse.py) there doesn't seem to be a way to configure this behaviour.

My suggestion(s) would be to:

- File a bug report with a patch :)

Or override / patch it:

- `print_*` method(s)
- `error` method.

The `print_*` method(s) seem to take an optional `file` argument which defaults to `_sys.stdout`.

**Update:** Alternatively you could do something like this whereby you redirect `sys.stdout` temporarily while you parse arguments:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def redirect_stdout_stderr(stream):
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    old_stderr = sys.stderr
    sys.stdout = stream
    sys.stderr = stream
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
        sys.stderr = old_stderr


with redirect_stdout_stderr(logstream):
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be no way to do this through the API.

However, you can do the following:

```
class LoggingArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    """Custom ArgumentPaarser that overrides _print_message"""

    def _print_message(self, message, file=None):
        if message:
            logger.write(message)
```

Comment: unfortunately there are also `print_usage` and others to catch

Comment: @wim No, those use `_print_message` internally.

Comment: Oh, you are right.  It may not be kosher to override a `_underscore` method though?  Your code can break without any warning because it is not public interface

Comment: @wim Definitely not kosher :)

Comment: Why did you define an `__init__` in the derived class, and not pass the args and kwargs through to the superclass?

Comment: @wim It's been a while since doing inheritance in Python - if I do not define `__init__` does it inherit automatically?

Comment: I just realised that.  You could call it, but pass `file=os.devnull`

Comment: It's true.  I'll just shutup now.  Actually I think tinkering in the `_underscore` methods is a bit fragile and hacky.  The redirection is perhaps a nicer way to do this, because you are guaranteed to catch any output even with future changes to the argparse module.  This method might cause output silently missing the logger (or even crashes) should argparse be updated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to call `super()._print_message(message, your_file)` within an `open(fpath) as your_file` block?

Answer (score 2):

While the answer given by @James Mills is great and solves the issue, there is no need for a generator in this case. Hence, the **yield** is redundant. Another way of achieving the same (without the generator) would be to write your own **context manager** without using the inbuilt **contextlib.contextmanager** decorator. Like the following.

```
class redirect_stdout_stderr(object):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        # Save the old std streams
        self.old_stream = sys.stdout
        self.old_error_stream = sys.stderr
        self.fstream = stream

    def __enter__(self):
        # Change the std streams to your streams when entering
        sys.stdout = self.fstream
        sys.stderr = self.fstream

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        # Change the std streams back to the original streams while exiting
        sys.stdout = self.old_stream
        sys.stderr = self.old_error_stream
```

In your case you can do something as follows.

```
with redirect_stdout_stderr(logstream):
    # __enter__() is executed
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # __exit__() is executed
```

Hope this helps!