# Python argparse errors to file

Tags: python, logging, argparse

I am trying to make a script that takes all errors and logs them to a log file.  I want to include any `argparse` errors to this file.  I already use the `logging` package and a `sys.excepthook` to drive unexpected exceptions to the log file.

Here's an example code:

```
import argparse
import logging
import sys
import traceback

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    logging.critical(''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb)))
    logging.critical('{0}: {1}'.format(ex_cls, ex))

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename='foo.log',
    filemode='w',
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

logging.debug('This is a typical debug line')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo String')
parser.add_argument('foo',type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
logging.debug('Input was %i'%(args.foo))
```

When I run it with `python logger_argparse.py 1` everything works great.  If I run `python logger_argparse.py a` I get the output in the console and not the log file:

```
usage: logger_argparse.py [-h] foo
logger_argparse.py: error: argument foo: invalid int value: 'a'
```

How do I get that information to go to the log file?

Comment: It doesn't work because `logger_argparse.py: error: argument foo: invalid int value: 'a'` is not a raised exception, it is just a printout from `argparse`.

Comment: Is there a good way to interupt that print to get it to go to the file?

Comment: In the `argparse.py` file, look at methods like `error` and `exit` (they are mentioned in the docs as well).  Most parsing errors raise `ArgumentError`, which is then captured by these, a message is printed to `stderr`, and then it calls `sys.exit`.

Comment: As search on [argparse] [logging] turned up this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935283/how-to-set-custom-output-handlers-for-argparse-in-python

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround that I don't believe is very good.  But it seems to be working:

```
import argparse
import logging
import sys
import traceback

class argparse_logger(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def _print_message(self, message, file=None):
        if file is sys.stderr:
            logger.error('Arg Parse did something bad...see below:')
            logger.error(message)
        else:
            super()._print_message(message,file=file)

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    logging.critical(''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb)))
    logging.critical('{0}: {1}'.format(ex_cls, ex))

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename='foo.log',
    filemode='w',
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# logging.getLogger('root')
logger = logging.getLogger('root')

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

logger.debug('This is a typical debug line')

parser = argparse_logger(description='Foo String')
parser.add_argument('foo',type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
logger.debug('Input was %i'%(args.foo))
```

Comment: I would have modified `parser.error`.  But since everything that it writes goes through `_print_message` your approach is just as good.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use [logging.exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) in an exception handler? 
Edit: so how about just logging from `ArgumentParser.error()`?

```
import sys
import logging
import argparse

class argparse_logger(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        logging.error(message)
        super().error(message)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename='foo.log',
    filemode='w',
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Foo")
parser = argparse_logger(description="Foo")
parser.add_argument('foo',type=int)
logging.debug("Start")

try:
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
except:
    print("Error handling arguments")
    raise
logging.debug(f"Finish - {args.foo}")
print(f"Exiting! - {args.foo}")
```

This will show the following:

```
J:\>python arg_parse_log.py 5
Exiting! - 5

J:\>more foo.log
2018-02-07 11:34:45,647 - DEBUG - Start
2018-02-07 11:34:45,648 - DEBUG - Finish - 5

J:\>python arg_parse_log.py
usage: arg_parse_log.py [-h] foo
arg_parse_log.py: error: the following arguments are required: foo
Error handling arguments

J:\>more foo.log
2018-02-07 11:34:54,577 - DEBUG - Start
2018-02-07 11:34:54,578 - ERROR - the following arguments are required: foo
```

Comment: Yes...but I wanted to capture the argparse printed errors to have a log of what was entered or missed.  The error just states that something went wrong...where the console output tells me what went wrong.